# Cannot open include file: 'log4cxx\logger.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, mfc, log4cxx, log4cplus

Is there any API for log4cxx?if so specify the location to download?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is - http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/download.html